# IE9 Area 51 commitment message cut off

Tags: bug, status-completed, area-51, design, commitment

Recently, I visited this page: http://area51.stackexchange.com/?tab=hot on Area 51.

I saw, on IE9 that the text to show I had commited to Chemistry was cut off at the top, unlike in Google Chrome.

Here is the screenshot with a freehand circle showing the problem.

[image: This shouldn't happen]

I am running IE9 in Windows 7.

I have deleted my cache etc, but I still have an issue, so I am reporting this as a bug.

Comment: +1 not because I expect IE to render anything properly but because I have sympathy for someone that uses it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The relevant CSS has be re-worked to accommodate IE, so it should be fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

Reproduced.  On Internet Explorer 9:

[image: commitment to Chemistry on Area 51 rendered in Internet Explorer 9.0.8112.16421]

On Google Chrome:

[image: commitment to Chemistry on Area 51 rendered in Google Chrome 16.0.912.77 m]